# Transform curve into linear

Tags: excel, math

How can I transform the blue curve values into linear (red curve)? I am doing some tests in excel, but basically I have those blue line values inside a 3D App that I want to manipulate with python so I can make those values linear. Is there any mathematical approach that I am missing?

The x axis goes from 0 to 90, and the y axis from 0 to 1.

For example: in the middle of the graph the blue line gives me a value of "0,70711", and I know that in linear it is "0,5". I was wondering if there's an easy formula to transform all the incoming non-linear values into linear.

I have no idea what "formula" is creating that non-linear blue line, also ignore the yellow line since I was just trying to "reverse engineer" to see if would lead me to any conclusion.

Thank you

[image: linear curve]

Comment: Are you trying to find the line that best fits the blue curve?

Comment: I want to transform the blue curve values to match the red one (linear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a linear function `y = ax + b` that for `x = 0` gives the value `1` and for `x = 90` gives `0`, just like the function that is represented by a blue curve.

In that case, your system of equations is the following:

```
1 = b // for x = 0
0 = a*90 + b // for x = 90
```

Solution provided by solver is the following : `{ a = -1/90, b = 1 }`, the red linear function will have form `y = ax + b`, we put the values of a and b we found from the solver and we discover that the linear function you are looking for is `y = -x/90 + 1` .

The tool I used to solve the system of equations:

http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~linear~linsolver.en.html

Comment: Sorry, I am not good with maths, let's say I have the value "0,70711" in the blue line, can you give me an example on how to make it linear?

Comment: Sure, let's say on the x = 10 (example) you have value 0,70711, you need to solve an equation: 0,70711 = a*10 + b, in other words, find numbers a and b that will make left side and right side of the equation equals. It doesn't make sence with one point, because you will have infinite number of solutions (imagine how many lines can go through a single point)... But once you have two, in that case first one and last one, you can build a system of two equations with one single solution, and it will be your linear function. Give me first and last point of your blue function and I will show you.

Comment: The curve (red or blue) is always 1 in the beginning, and 0 in the end. In the x goes from 0 to 90. One problem is that I don't have access to x (0-90) in the 3D App where I need to manipulate the values. The only values I have are the blue line (non-linear). Thank you

Comment: In that case, your system of equations is the following:
1 = b // for x = 0
0 = a*90 + b // for x = 90
Solution provided by solver is the following : `{ a = -1/90, b = 1 }`, the red linear function will have form `y = ax + b`, we put the values of a and b we found from the solver and we discover that the linear function you are looking for is `y = -x/90 + 1` .

The tool I used to solve the system of equations:

http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~linear~linsolver.en.html

Comment: -x/90 + 1 works, but I dont have access to x as I told in the last comment. Maybe this is not doable I guess. Thanks anyway Marek

Comment: I'm not sure I understand `I don't have access to x`, could you please explain? I think I know what you mean, you have only the values of blue curve.
In that case you have two possibilities, find the index of the value given by blue curve (for example by enumerating them or indexing...) or find function inverse to the blue function, inverse function let's you find x from y.

Comment: yeh, in the 3D App I only have the blue lines, i could use python to get the x with the index, but I was wondering if i could use only a "math node" that let's me do multiplication and division, but no iteration.

What you mean by "or find function inverse to the blue function, inverse function let's you find x from y"

Comment: I think that was what i did with the yellow line in the graph, but I still need x value for that right?

Comment: Every mathematical function can be defined as `f(x) = y`, and we can say that for some (I'm not sure if for all) functions there exist inverse function `f(y)^(-1) = x`. In other words, `f` takes `x` and gives you `y` and `f^(-1)` takes `y` and gives you `x`. If you find function inverse to the one that draws blue curve, you will be able to find `x` using only math mode.

Comment: Let's say we have three functions. `f` is the one that gives you your blue curve. `g` is inverse function to `f` and `l` is the linear red line function we just found. `f` and `l` are known, `g` is function to be found, but let's say we have all of them. To find red line value from blue line value you would simply do the following : `y = l(g(f))`

Comment: thanks Marek, I will see how can I solve this with your helpful info , I shouldn't have missed so many math classes :D

Comment: No problem. Here I leave you some usefull info with examples of finding inverse function:
http://www.purplemath.com/modules/invrsfcn3.htm

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean? You can calculate points on the red line like this:

```
f(x) = 1-x/90
```

and the point then is `(x,f(x))` = `(x, 1-x/90)`. But to be honest, I think your question is still rather unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex. Sorry for the confusion, what I need is to transform any value in the blue line into the red one (linear). And I have only the blue line values inside the 3D App, so i need a formula to "linearize" those values.

Comment: 1-x/90 works but I don't have x inside the 3D App, I have only the blue line values.